# Merge a remote branch on Heroku to Heroku Master to trigger a build

Tags: git, heroku, heroku-cli

I have pushed some changes to a remote branch on Heroku, I need to merge this branch to my master branch on Heroku to trigger a new build of the app. Can this be done? Can this be done using Heroku-cli?

Comment: Why are you trying to merge the branch on Heroku? Normally that would happen on your local machine, or maybe on GitHub via a pull request, and the resultant branch would be deployed to Heroku.

Comment: The reason I'm trying this because whenever I try to push to heroku master, it doesn't push changes and only says that everything is up to date. This is after changing code on the local branch and committing. I do not know what the problem is now. So I pushed to another branch on Heroku and thought I'd ask if I can merge to master.

Comment: Nvm I figured out the problem thanks in part to the answer I accepted. Thank you for your help.

Comment: That's because [Heroku only deploys from its `master` branch](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploying-code). You can merge to your local `master` and push that, or [push a non-`master` local branch to Heroku's `master`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploying-from-a-branch-besides-master).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heroku isn't a version control hosting service so you won't be able to perform a merge between branches you've pushed to Heroku. Only pushes to the `master` branch on your `heroku` remote will be built. If you need to push a local, non-master branch you can do something like this: `git push heroku local-branch:master` to trigger a build. They have documentation for this [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploying-from-a-branch-besides-master).

Comment: You are time saver :)